# How to setup the z-index of multiple elements and updating them dynamically using javascript inside modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a code when user click on any `div` modal open and inside the modal all the div grouped together and work as a slider. But I want to give the highest `z-index` on the div which is clicked by the user and then carry the next and previous button functionality according to the highest `z-index` div.

Currently, when we are clicking on div the modal appears and set the highest z-index on the last slide and then the next and previous button work accordingly.

Below is the code:-

```js
$(function() {

            $('.gallery-wrapper').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    galleryPopup = $this.find('.gallery-popup'),
                    prevBtn = $this.find('.prev-btn'),
                    nextBtn = $this.find('.next-btn'),
                    posts = $this.find('.post'),
                    current = 0


                // -------- Opening popup by clicking on any item-link
                // --------------------------------------------

                $this.find('.item-link').on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    galleryPopup.fadeIn();
                    $('body, html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                });

                // -------- Closing popup by clicking on close-link
                // --------------------------------------------

                $this.find('.close-link').on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    galleryPopup.fadeOut();
                    $('body, html').css('overflow', 'initial');
                });



                // -------- Popup slider script
                // --------------------------------------------

                var galleryWrapper = document.querySelector('.gallery-wrapper');
                var controls = galleryWrapper.querySelector('.button-holder');
                var els = galleryWrapper.querySelectorAll('.post');
                var order = Object.keys(els);
                var cn;
                var highestElm;

                function setZIndex() {
                    for (var i in order) els[order[i]].style.zIndex = i;
                }

                function findHighestZIndex(elem) {
                    var highest = 0;
                    var highestElement = null;
                    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(elem);

                    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                        var style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elems[i], null);
                        var zindex = style.getPropertyValue("z-index");

                        if ((zindex != 'auto') && (+zindex > highest)) {
                            highest = zindex;
                            highestElement = elems[i];
                        }
                    }

                    return highestElement;
                }


                // assign a click handler to the parent
                controls.onclick = function(e) {
                    var elem = findHighestZIndex('post');
                    var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelector('.collection').children);
                    highestElm = Number(nodes.indexOf(elem));

                    if (!(cn = (e.target.className.match(/prev-btn|next-btn/) || [false])[0])) return;

                    if (cn === "prev-btn") {

                        if (highestElm == 0) {
                            var lastChildElem = galleryWrapper.querySelector('.collection').lastElementChild;
                            lastChildElem.classList.add('animate-out');
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                lastChildElem.classList.remove('animate-out');
                            }, 300);
                        } else {
                            els[highestElm - 1].classList.add('animate-out');
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                els[highestElm - 1].classList.remove('animate-out');
                            }, 300);
                        }
                        order.unshift(order.pop());
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            setZIndex();
                        }, 400);
                    }

                    if (cn === "next-btn") {
                        els[highestElm].classList.add('animate');

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            els[highestElm].classList.remove('animate');
                            setZIndex();
                        }, 300);
                        order.push(order.shift());
                        setZIndex();
                    }
                }

                setZIndex();
            });
        });
```

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        body {
            overflow-x: hidden !important;
        }
        
        .gallery-popup {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        .collection {
            max-width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            perspective: 1500px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 120px;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .post {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 300px;
            height: 400px;
            background: orangered;
            border: 5px solid #fff;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-size: 4rem;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transition: transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.57, 0.09, 0.105, 1.005);
        }
        
        .post img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
        
        .animate {
            transform: translate3d(350px, 25px, -400px);
            z-index: 999 !important;
        }
        
        .animate-out {
            transform: translate3d(380px, 85px, -590px);
            z-index: -1 !important;
            /* keygrame if needed */
        }
        
        .button-holder {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .button-holder button {
            margin: 5px;
            width: 70px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 0;
            border: none;
            background: orangered;
            color: #fff;
        }
        
        .close-link {
            color: #fff;
            position: absolute;
            right: 15px;
            top: 15px;
            width: 35px;
            height: 35px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            line-height: 34px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-family: 'Arial';
            background: orangered;
        }
        
        .gallery-row {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            padding: 15px;
            margin-left: -10px;
            margin-right: -10px;
        }
        
        .gallery-row .item {
            padding: 10px;
            flex: 0 0 25%;
            max-width: 25%;
            height: 250px;
            background: orangered;
            border: 2px solid #fff;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        .gallery-row .item a {
            display: flex;
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
        .gallery-row .item img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
    <div class="gallery-row">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <span>1</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <span>2</span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <span>3</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <span>4</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <span>5</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Gallery Popup -->
    <div class="gallery-popup">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close-link">x</a>
        <div class="collection">
            <div class="post">
                <span>1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <span>2</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <span>3</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <span>4</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <span>5</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="button-holder">
            <div>
                <button class="prev-btn">Previous</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="next-btn">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Gallery Popup -->
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
$(function() {

            $('.gallery-wrapper').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    galleryPopup = $this.find('.gallery-popup'),
                    prevBtn = $this.find('.prev-btn'),
                    nextBtn = $this.find('.next-btn'),
                    posts = $this.find('.post'),
                    current = 0


                // -------- Opening popup by clicking on any item-link
                // --------------------------------------------

                $this.find('.item-link').on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    setOrderClicked($(event.target));
                    galleryPopup.fadeIn();
                    $('body, html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                });

                // -------- Closing popup by clicking on close-link
                // --------------------------------------------

                $this.find('.close-link').on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    galleryPopup.fadeOut();
                    $('body, html').css('overflow', 'initial');
                });



                // -------- Popup slider script
                // --------------------------------------------

                var galleryWrapper = document.querySelector('.gallery-wrapper');
                var controls = galleryWrapper.querySelector('.button-holder');
                var els = galleryWrapper.querySelectorAll('.post');
                var order = Object.keys(els);
                var cn;
                var highestElm;
                
                function setOrderClicked(el) {
                    var index = $('.item-link').index(el);
                  
                  order = [];
                  
                  for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
                    index = (index === els.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1);
                    order.push(index.toString());
                  };
                  
                  setZIndex();
                };

                function setZIndex(){
                    for (var i in order) els[order[i]].style.zIndex = i;
                }

                function findHighestZIndex(elem) {
                    var highest = 0;
                    var highestElement = null;
                    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(elem);

                    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                        var style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elems[i], null);
                        var zindex = style.getPropertyValue("z-index");

                        if ((zindex != 'auto') && (+zindex > highest)) {
                            highest = zindex;
                            highestElement = elems[i];
                        }
                    }

                    return highestElement;
                }


                // assign a click handler to the parent
                controls.onclick = function(e) {
                    var elem = findHighestZIndex('post');
                    var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelector('.collection').children);
                    highestElm = Number(nodes.indexOf(elem));

                    if (!(cn = (e.target.className.match(/prev-btn|next-btn/) || [false])[0])) return;

                    if (cn === "prev-btn") {

                        if (highestElm == 0) {
                            var lastChildElem = galleryWrapper.querySelector('.collection').lastElementChild;
                            lastChildElem.classList.add('animate-out');
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                lastChildElem.classList.remove('animate-out');
                            }, 300);
                        } else {
                            els[highestElm - 1].classList.add('animate-out');
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                els[highestElm - 1].classList.remove('animate-out');
                            }, 300);
                        }
                        order.unshift(order.pop());
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            setZIndex();
                        }, 400);
                    }

                    if (cn === "next-btn") {
                        els[highestElm].classList.add('animate');

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            els[highestElm].classList.remove('animate');
                            setZIndex();
                        }, 300);
                        order.push(order.shift());
                        setZIndex();
                    }
                }

                setZIndex();
            });
        });
```

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        body {
            overflow-x: hidden !important;
        }
        
        .gallery-popup {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        .collection {
            max-width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            perspective: 1500px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 120px;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .post {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 300px;
            height: 400px;
            background: orangered;
            border: 5px solid #fff;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-size: 4rem;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transition: transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.57, 0.09, 0.105, 1.005);
        }
        
        .post img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
        
        .animate {
            transform: translate3d(350px, 25px, -400px);
            z-index: 999 !important;
        }
        
        .animate-out {
            transform: translate3d(380px, 85px, -590px);
            z-index: -1 !important;
            /* keygrame if needed */
        }
        
        .button-holder {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .button-holder button {
            margin: 5px;
            width: 70px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 0;
            border: none;
            background: orangered;
            color: #fff;
        }
        
        .close-link {
            color: #fff;
            position: absolute;
            right: 15px;
            top: 15px;
            width: 35px;
            height: 35px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            line-height: 34px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-family: 'Arial';
            background: orangered;
        }
        
        .gallery-row {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            padding: 15px;
            margin-left: -10px;
            margin-right: -10px;
        }
        
        .gallery-row .item {
            padding: 10px;
            flex: 0 0 25%;
            max-width: 25%;
            height: 250px;
            background: orangered;
            border: 2px solid #fff;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        .gallery-row .item a {
            display: flex;
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
        .gallery-row .item img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
    <div class="gallery-row">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <span>1</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <span>2</span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <span>3</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <span>4</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <span>5</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Gallery Popup -->
    <div class="gallery-popup">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close-link">x</a>
        <div class="collection">
            <div class="post">
                <span>1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <span>2</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <span>3</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <span>4</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <span>5</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="button-holder">
            <div>
                <button class="prev-btn">Previous</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="next-btn">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Gallery Popup -->
  </div>
```

The key to opening the modal viewer to display a specific div is to understand what the `order` array looks like when each div is displayed:

```
index, order
0, ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
1, ["1", "2", "3", "4", "0"]
2, ["2", "3", "4", "0", "1"]
3, ["3", "4", "0", "1", "2"]
4, ["4", "0", "1", "2", "3"]
```

For example, to display div 2 (index = 1), `order` must be `["1", "2", "3", "4", "0"]`.

The `setOrderClicked` function has been added to set the `order` array according to the index of the clicked div. It is called from the `.item-link` click event. First, it uses the [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function to find the index of the div which was clicked. Then it rebuilds the `order` array to match the above pattern. Finally, it calls `setZIndex` to apply the new `z-index` values.

Comment: It worked you are a life saviour. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome! That CSS animation is so nice BTW, well done on that :)